React native on scroll jumps index
I am creating a flatlist in react native with on scroll.
I have 9 items on my list and I am also using the indicator to scroll through the 9 items. Now, the indicator scrolls fast and finishes quickly before we get to the end of the items.
Like it gets to the end when the item is at number 5, so it is inconsistent. I want it to scroll item by item consistently.
Here is my code below:
viewModel.ts:
 @observable currentIndex: number = 0
 actionCardsData = [
    {
      id: "1",
      icon: "coin",
      text: "rewards.exploreHomeReward",
      desciption: "rewards.homeofRewardsDescription",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      icon: "handIconRewards",
      text: "rewards.guaranteedRewardsTitle",
      desciption: "rewards.guaranteedRewardsDescription",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      icon: "iconHeartFillRewards",
      text: "rewards.annualBirthdaydRewardsTitle",
      desciption: "rewards.annualBirthdaydRewardsDescription",
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      icon: "buyCartsIconRewards",
      text: "rewards.uberEatsVouchersRewardsTitle",
      desciption: "rewards.uberEatsVouchersRewardsDescription",
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      icon: "benefitsCompetitionsIconRewards",
      text: "rewards.competitionEntriesRewardsTitle",
      desciption: "rewards.competitionEntriesRewardsDescription",
    },
    {
      id: "6",
      icon: "boxOfficeIconRewards",
      text: "rewards.boxOfficeRentalRewardsTitle",
      desciption: "rewards.boxOfficeRentalRewardsDescription",
    },
    {
      id: "7",
      icon: "upgradePackageRewards",
      text: "rewards.packageUpgradesRewardsTitle",
      desciption: "rewards.packageUpgradesRewardsDescription",
    },
    {
      id: "8",
      icon: "newShowmaxIcon",
      text: "rewards.showmaxDiscountsRewardsTitle",
      desciption: "rewards.showmaxDiscountsRewardsDescription",
    },
    {
      id: "9",
      icon: "addMoviesIconsRewards",
      text: "rewards.boxOfficeRentalRewardsTitle",
      desciption: "rewards.movieAddOnDiscountsRewardsDescription",
    },
  ]
 @action.bound
  setCurrentIndex(index: number) {
    this.currentIndex = index
  }

  @action.bound
  updateIndex(contentOffsetX: number, cardWidth: number, spacing: number) {
    let newIndex = Math.round(contentOffsetX / (cardWidth + spacing))
    this.setCurrentIndex(Math.min(newIndex, this.actionCardsData.length - 1))
  }

my index.tsx:
const visibleIndicators = (currentIndex) => {
    const maxIndicators =
      viewModel.actionCardsData.length > 9 ? 9 : viewModel.actionCardsData.length
    let start = Math.max(0, currentIndex - Math.floor(maxIndicators / 2))
    const end = Math.min(viewModel.actionCardsData.length, start + maxIndicators)
    start = Math.max(0, end - maxIndicators)
    return Array.from({ length: end - start }, (_, i) => start + i).map(renderIndicator)
  }
  const updateIndex = (event) => {
    const contentOffsetX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
    viewModel.updateIndex(contentOffsetX, cardWidth, Spacings.Cozy)
    
  }
<FlatList
        data={viewModel.actionCardsData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        decelerationRate="fast"
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        onScroll={updateIndex}
        horizontal
        snapToInterval={cardWidth + Spacings.Roomy}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ width: Spacings.Cozy }} />}
      />
      {viewModel.actionCardsData.length > 2 && (
        <View style={styles.indicatorContainer}>{visibleIndicators(viewModel.currentIndex)}</View>
      )}

Can you please check what I am not doing correct and assist please.

I managed to find a solution. So, the cards are bigger in size meaning that the indicator scroll take the spacing of the items when scrolling according to my logic.
So I had to update my spacing size to cater for the card size and to scroll through the entire list
const updateIndex = (event) => {
const contentOffsetX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
viewModel.updateIndex(contentOffsetX, cardWidth, Spacings.Cozy)//spacing.cozy was equal to 24, had to increase this by 180 to work
}
